# Translucent UINavigationController, presented modally

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uikit

How can one present a `UINavigationController` such that the view it was presented from is still visible in the background?

My experience is that the `UINavigationController` will clip anything below its view, so setting `UINavigationController.view.alpha` will uncover a fixed color background, not the presenting view's content.

Can this be changed?

**EDIT**

I am not interested in the navigation bar, but the full content the navigation controller manages.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not the UINavigationController, but the fact that you present it modally. ViewControllers presented modally can never be transparent.

You can fake a modal presentation by adding you UINavigationControllers view as a subview to the main UIWindow.

This example works for me when testing in XCode:

```
   UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
   viewController.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor greenColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.35];

   UINavigationController *navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];

   [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:navCon.view];
```

Of course you will have to do any animated transition yourself, but that should be trivial using animation blocks.

Comment: How do you then remove it? I've tried [self.view removeFromSuperview] and [self.navigationController.view removeFromSuperview], but you cant interact with the original view

Comment: Your navigation controller is being release after you present it. Remember that adding it's view as a subview on the UIWindow will only retain the navigation controller's view, not the actual navigation controller. So you need to keep it alive by assigning it to a ivar, a strong property or a collection.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a way to achieve this using the iOS7 custom transitions, this way :

```
MyController * controller = [MyController new];
[controller setTransitioningDelegate:self.transitionController];
controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
[self controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

To create your custom transition, you need 2 things :

- A TransitionDelegate object (implementing
  `<UIViewControllerTransitionDelegate>`)
- An "AnimatedTransitioning" object 
  (implementing `<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>`)

You can find more informations on custom transitions in this tutorial : http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/ios-7-custom-transitions/

Answer (score 0):

if you wish this behavior you can not use a `UINavigationController`, as you say the navigation controller clip the view of the content controller. To do what you want you should add a navigator bar to your view instead, and simulate the actions of the navigation controller. To create a back button similar to the controller read [this article](http://idevrecipes.com/2011/01/12/how-do-iphone-apps-instagramreederdailybooth-implement-custom-navigationbar-with-variable-width-back-buttons/)

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to understand what is going on and why this is happening and why it can't be changed if it can't be changed. (I am working on an existing project and rewriting the navcontroller would be too much hassle.)